# Windows live sdk not working in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cordova, sdk, emulation

I have installed windows live sdk to my visual studio 2012 .I tried to add quick reference javascript library in visual studio . I have tried following methord described in blog
    Install the Live SDK, if you have not already done so.
    In your project, in Solution Explorer, right-click References > Add Reference.
    Click Windows > Extension SDKs > Live SDK for Windows Store app.
    Click Add, and then click Close.
But there is no Windows option in my visual studio

Comment: Pls accept ans if u find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to get it.

Download and unzip the Cordova 3 Source
Run the template.bat in the cordova-wp8 folder
Copy the generated Zip files to your Visual studio template folder

also follow below link for windows mobile .

1-http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/installing-phonegap-and

or===============or=================or================

follow this steps

Ignore the installation documentation and all the command line, node.js stuff (seriously you will waste hours on this.
Go to github and simply download the PhoneGap master .zip
In that zip are project files for window phone, etc platform... just use those templates.